# map with typescript(javascipt) with object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

hello i would like to create a map based on these if .. is there a way to create a map and write better code?

```
findViewDetailPolicy(policy) {
        if (policy['displayInfo']['displayTypeDetail']['displayType'] === 'STANDARD') {
          this.path = this.policyPathDetailStandard;
          this.router.navigate([this.path]);
        }
        if (policy['displayInfo']['displayTypeDetail']['displayType'] === 'PACCHETTO') {
          this.path = this.policyPathDetailModulare;
          this.router.navigate([this.path]);
        }
        if (policy['displayInfo']['displayTypeDetail']['displayType'] === 'SAVING') {
          this.path = this.policyPathDetailSaving;
          this.router.navigate([this.path]);
        }
        if (policy['displayInfo']['displayTypeDetail']['displayType'] === 'CQ') {
          this.path = this.policyPathDetailCq;
          this.router.navigate([this.path]);
        }
        if (policy['displayInfo']['displayTypeDetail']['displayType'] === 'COLLETTIVA') {
          this.path = this.policyPathDetailCollective;
          this.router.navigate([this.path]);
        }
      }
```

Comment: switch case could do the job. Check docs. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: not map but the better way is try to put `policy['displayInfo']['displayTypeDetail']['displayType']` in a variable and write those conditions in  a much better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can be boiled down  to:

```
findViewDetailPolicy(policy) {
    const map = { STANDARD: this.policyPathDetailStandard, ... };
    this.path = map[policy['displayInfo']['displayTypeDetail']['displayType']];
    this.router.navigate([this.path]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The map could be like this:

```
const mapToPathProp = {
    STANDARD: "policyPathDetailStandard",
    PACCHETTO: "policyPathDetailModulare",
    SAVING: "policyPathDetailSaving",
    CQ: "policyPathDetailCq",
    COLLETTIVA: "policyPathDetailCollective"
};
```

And then:

```
findViewDetailPolicy(policy) {
    let pathProp = mapToPathProp[policy.displayInfo.displayTypeDetail.displayType];
    if (pathProp) {
        this.path = this[pathProp];
        this.router.navigate([this.path]);
    }
}
```

Comment: const mapToPathProp = {
    STANDARD: "policyPathDetailStandard",
    PACCHETTO: "policyPathDetailModulare",
    SAVING: "policyPathDetailSaving",
    CQ: "policyPathDetailCq",
    COLLETTIVA: "policyPathDetailCollective"
};

Comment: in this object ..
with which method you pass the property of path in object

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. `pathProp` will for instance be "polidyPathDetailStandard", and `this[pathProp]` will then be as if you did `this.polidyPathDetailStandard`. Does this clarify it? The advantage of this method is that you create a map only once, not every time you call your function. Also, the accepted answer does not have the same behaviour as your code when there is no match with any of the `if` conditions.